# How to make a UILabel work as a url that's clickable and has url effect (when getting clicked)?

Tags: iphone, url, uilabel

I know there is three20 solution. But I don't want to use three20 just for that purpose. So programmingly, is there a solution for that?

Comment: Please refer to my answer. I am sure that will provide you a good solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is a solution. You can use the regular expression to detect particular kind of strings on touches began of the label and then based on the regular expression which matches the string you can perform the action.

So if you want to do that, you need to subclass the UILabel and overwrite the Touch methods for the label.

Hope this helps you.

There is one of the Label's called [OHAttributedLabel](https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHAttributedLabel) which does similar function. And here is a [fork](https://github.com/greenisus/OHAttributedLabel), that supports ARC.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `UIButton` with the button type as `UIButtonTypeCustom`, on the button click you can call the url.

```
UIButton *urlButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
urlButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 30);
[urlButton setTitle:@"Click Here" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[urlButton addTarget:self action:@selector(urlButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:urlButton];
```

Comment: Question is about UILabel and not UIButton.